# Angular: how to generate the core styles in a CSS file instead of injecting the style in style tags?

Tags: angular

When I import a component (for example MatTabsModule), it generates in the head section:

```
<style>.mdc-tab{min-width:90px;padding-right:24px....</style>
```

I would like to generate all these styles in a CSS file.
How can I do that?

I already tried to change optimization settings, but it doesn't work. For example:

```
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": true
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**. Angular **only** create styles tags, if you're using in one component:`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. You need understand what makes [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation).

The solution is not use in any component. (Really it's a bad practice). I know that when we use material, most of the time we need apply a "global style" (mainly it's because material use ckd-overlay in several components, and a cdk-overlay is "out of reach" your component).

Instead of use ViewEncapsulation.None, check if the component have a property like "panelClass", give a property, e.g. "custom" and add your .css in "styles.css"

```
.custom .your-class{
   ...
}
```

You can also add the class in styles.css and this class is applied to all the aplication

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Eliseo. I understood the principle of encapsulation. So, it is not possible to block the generation of style tags, and manually import these basic styles into my global style.scss?
I am afraid in terms of performance. Without using external CSS files, it adds to the weight of the page and does not allow caching. No?

Comment: To be clear, my goal is to reduce the page weight and improve performance. I could manually import the core css (I know exactly the components I need)

Comment: Angular create an unique "styles.css" based in the .css you have in your components + the files in .css you indicate in angular.json (in projects-->Architects-->build->styles). (see, e.g. this [link](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/introduction-to-styling-and-style-isolation-angular) to know how work. When you use in a component ViewEncapsulation.None, the .css in your component have not inside the "styles.css" else in the index using styles tag. So if you have styles tag is because you have use ViewEncapsulation.None in any component.

Comment: the "caching" are avoid because when you build an aplication by defect the name of the "styles.css" generated is "bundled", e.g. is some like "styles.aac2334jkkc.css"